What is meant by the phrase ' sat at meat '?
Matthew 9:10 is presented in slightly different phraseology from Version to Version, for instance :
King James Bible

And it came to pass, as Jesus sat at meat in the house, behold, many publicans and sinners came and sat down with him and his disciples.

New King James Version

Now it happened, as Jesus sat at the table in the house, that behold, many tax collectors and sinners came and sat down with Him and His disciples.

A  few other versions like ASB also use the phrase ' sat at meat ' . Does it mean that meat was an essential ingredient of dinners that Jews served to guests ? Or, was it meant to denote all kinds of meal including vegetarian meals ? How do Bible scholars interpret the phrase ?

+1. Interesting comparison. It really shows the semantic change where "the modern meaning is radically different from the original usage."

One of the problems of relying upon the KJV is that some of the English words themselves have changed their meaning over the intervening centuries.
(Compare with words like "gay" and "gender" over only the last few decades.)
In 1611, the English word "meat" didn't have the same meaning as it does today:

meat (noun):
Middle English mēte, from Old English mete "food, nourishment, sustenance" (paired with drink), "item of food; animal food, fodder," also "a meal, repast, …
…
Narrower sense of "flesh of warm-blooded animals killed and used as food" is attested from c. 1300 (earlier this was flesh-meat, early 12c.).
— meat | Online Etymology Dictionary.

This English usage can be seen in the first book of the Bible, Genesis 1:29:

And God said, Behold, I have given you every herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed; to you it shall be for meat.

Modern translations have "to you it shall be for food" for the last phrase.
The original Greek of Matthew 9:10 doesn't even mention food though.
"sat at meat" is a loose translation of ἀνάκειμαι (anakeimai), which means:

to lie at a table, eat together, dine
— G345 - anakeimai - Strong's Greek Lexicon (kjv).

Modern translation don't mention food either:

(CSB) While he was reclining at the table in the house, many tax collectors and sinners came to eat with Jesus and his disciples.
(NIV) While Jesus was having dinner at Matthew’s house, many tax collectors and sinners came and ate with him and his disciples.
(NLT) Later, Matthew invited Jesus and his disciples to his home as dinner guests, along with many tax collectors and other disreputable sinners.


One of my favourite little 'factlets' is (unless I'm very much mistaken) that of all the various offerings enumerated in the Book of Leviticus (the burnt offering, the peace offering, the wave offering, etc.) the 'meat offering' (as it is termed in the KJV, the NIV and the ESV call it a 'grain offering') is the only one that doesn't involve any animals

Short Answer: This is a case of semantic change where "the modern meaning is radically different from the original usage."
The word used in Matthew 9:10 according to the Strong's Greek is ἀνακειμένου (anakeimenou).
This is from the word:

Original Word: ἀνάκειμαι
Transliteration: anakeimai
Definition: to be laid up, to recline
Usage: I recline, especially at a dinner-table.

So, the phrase does not mean that meat was an ingredient of the meal. Rather, it simply means that Jesus was sharing a meal with others.

ἀνακειμένου] In classical Greek, to recline at table is represented by
κατακεῖσθαι, as frequently also in the N. T. (Mark 2:15; Mark 14:3),
though in Polybius, Athenaeus, and later writers ἀνακεῖσθαι, too, is
by no means rare. (Meyer's NT Commentary)


Here is my very literal translation of Matt 9:10 -

And it came to pass of Him reclining in the house that behold,
many tax collectors and sinners came reclining with Jesus and His
disciples.

The operative verb here is ἀνάκειμαι (anakeimai) which means to lie and recline.  Now, with the exception of the single disputed instance in the Byzantine MSS in Mark 5:40, this verb always means, "to recline at a table in order to eat a meal".  Thus, BDAG gives the meaning, "dine".
Further, at the time of the KJV translation the English word "meat" simply meant "food".  Thus, the KJV translation, "sat at meat" is "kinda" correct except for the fact that people did not sit at a table but reclined at a table.  Thus, modern versions render this verb as:

having dinner, NIV
reclined at table, ESV (except that "at table" is not in the Greek but implied)
dining, BSB
reclining, BLB (this is the most literally correct)
sat at the table, NKJV
reclining at the table, NASB, which by use of the italics acknowledged that "at table" is added
etc


Thanks, Dottard, for the scholarly inputs. I have posted a question on CSE on ' reclining '.  The table which Jews used at the time of Jesus may have been pretty different from what we have today. The participants of the meal did not sit on chairs of say, three to five feet height as we have today. They instead took position on a mat or cushion spread on the floor , in a semi lying posture. Table if any, was short in height so as to facilitate easy access from the floor.
